# Load multiple .csv-files into one table and create ID per .csv -postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

Heyho. I am using Postgresql 9.5 and I am desperating at a problem.
I have multiple .csv-Files (40) and all of them have the same columncount und -names. I would now like to import them into one table, but I want an ID per .csv-file. Is it possible to automate this in postgres? (including adding a new id column) And how?

The approach might look like this:

```
test1.csv ==> table_agg ==> set ID = 1
test2.csv ==> table_agg ==> set ID = 2
.
.
.
test40.csv ==> table_agg ==> set ID = 40
```

I would be very glad if someone could help me

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it this way? (vs. adding some sort of dataset identifier to each row and just use one table...)

Comment: I could make it so, that's true, but then I have to assign an ID for each loaded table. test1: ID=1, test2: ID=2,...I will update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a table that contains the filename and other info you would like to add to each dataset. Add a `serial` column, that you can use as a foreign key in your data table, i.e. a dataset identifier.

Create the data table. Add a foreign key field to refer to the dataset entry in the other table.

Use a Python script to parse and import the csv files into the database. First add the entry to the datasets table. Then determine the dataset ID and insert the rows into the data table with the corresponding dataset ID set.

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution to assign an ID to each .csv-file in Python and to output all .csv-files in one.

```
import glob, os, pandas as pd

path =r'PathToFolder'
# all .csv-files in this folder
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

# safe DFs in list_
list_ = []
# DF for later concat
frame = pd.DataFrame()
# ID per DF/.csv
count = 0

for file_ in allFiles:

    # read .csv-files
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None,skiprows=[1], header=0)
    # new column with ID per DF
    df['new_id'] = count
    list_.append(df)
    count = count + 1

frame = pd.concat(list_)
frame.to_csv('PathToOuputCSV', index = False)
```

Continue with SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE statement..
COPY TABLE_NAME FROM 'PathToCSV' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```